# linux to linux remote desktop

Tags: linux

how do I do remote desktop connection from unix to unix, analogous to that of windows remote desktop?

Comment: Do you want X or command line ?

Comment: either is fine, the ssh -Y worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. X11 is network-transparent : use "ssh -Y" to connect to another machine, launch any application and poof, it appears right on your screen. Of course it's tailored for local area networks...

If you really want to see a complete desktop, it's slightly different; usually you'd use VNC. For instance GDM comes with optional VNC support, so that you can open a remote session with any VNC client if it's enabled.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to take a look at No Machine.

From wikipedia:

> NX technology is a computer program
>   that handles remote X Window System
>   connections, and attempts to greatly
>   improve on the performance of the
>   native X display protocol to the point
>   that it can be usable over a slow link
>   such as a dial-up modem.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology
- http://www.nomachine.com/

Comment: +1 second the NX recommendation. The best solution IMHO.

Comment: yes! VNC's ok, but NX is teh hot ness :)

Comment: NX is amazing.  I started using it after reading this post.  It's free, easy to install, and allows you to login to a new session, and maintain it while you are disconnected.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to look into XVNC or XRDP.

Answer (score 0):

```
xinit -e ssh -XY user@ip_address "/usr/bin/xfce4-session" -- :1
```

Will start a full X session with the window manager and all, pretty much like RDP in windows, it is actually tailored for LAN as mentioned by wazoox, via web you might wanna try VNC or NX.